# golang gin and socketio

Tags: go, socket.io

How to use `gin.Context.MustGet()` in `server := socketio.NewServer(nil)`

I used **authorized** to check the token and before into socketio handler.

```
authorized.GET("/socket.io", gin.WrapH(server))
authorized.POST("/socket.io", gin.WrapH(server))
```

I set some information for the client in **authorized**.

```
func AuthRequired(c *gin.Context) {
    ...
    c.Set("username", claims.Username) // parse from the token
    ...
}
```

I know I can do this to get the **username** from gin.Context

```
authorized.GET("/content", func(c *gin.Context) {
    fmt.Println(c.MustGet("username"))
    ...
})
```

Is there any way to get the **username** from the server? Or how to pass the variable into here?

```
server.OnEvent("/", "chat", func(s socketio.Conn, msg string) string {
    fmt.Println("chat: ", msg)
    s.Emit("response", msg)
    return "recv " + msg
})
```

Although there is `s.RemoteHeader()` that I can get the token and parse it, it is repeated to parse it again.

Answer (score 0):

you should add username from AuthRequired like below:

```
c.Request.Header.Set("username", claims.Username)
```

and then use it in server.OnEvent function like below:

```
s.RemoteHeader().Get("username")
```